# Pear Can't send email on Shared Hosting

Tags: php, mysql, email, pear

I was working on a project for a client, it selects an email from a database and then sends an email to that address. Everything worked fine on my VPS server running CentOS 6, but when migrating to their shared hosting the program will no longer send the email. It will select the correct addresses, but no message will be sent, I've already installed Pear Mail and Mail_mime. Any thoughts?

This code connects to the server:

```
$headers['From']    = 'mail@openmailbox.org'; 
$headers['To']      = 'mail@openmailbox.org'; 
$headers['Subject'] = $asunto;




$params['host'] = 'smtp.openmailbox.org';
$params['port'] = '25';
$params['auth'] = 'PLAIN';
$params['username'] = 'mail@openmailbox.org';
$params['password'] = 'password';
```

This code selects the recipients:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$addresses[] = $row['email'];
}
$recipients = implode(", ", $addresses);
```

Hope you can help me!

Comment: No, that is the weirdest thing. I receive the message that list the email addresses of the receivers, but it is not sent. Some hours ago I was getting a implode error, but that is fixed now.

Comment: Are you using mail() function or what?

Comment: what is your exact mail sending code?

Comment: You've not included any code relevant to the problem you're experiencing, asides from some config settings. We can't help unless you provide more info.

Comment: I provided more information below, hope you can help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved it. I replaced pear mail with the default mail function.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this is my email sending code

```
$mail =& Mail::factory('smtp', $params);



    $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);

    $mime->setTXTBody($text);
    $mime->setHTMLBody($html);

    $body = $mime->get();
    $headers = $mime->headers($headers);


    $mail->send($recipients, $headers, $body);
```